# How to have `SPACE: magic-space` in ~/.inputrc without breaking Python 3 REPL?

Tags: bash, debian, terminal, python, readline

If I put `SPACE: magic-space` in my `~/.inputrc` file for configuring Readline, then I cannot enter `SPACE`s in `python3` REPL (v3.8.7)

How can I use `SPACE: magic-space` in my `~/.inputrc` without breaking `python3`?

NB: Is the only solution to move `SPACE: magic-space` into `~/.bashrc` (and do the same for all other applications where I'd like that key binding enable)?

Answer (score 1):

The `inputrc` file [supports conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Init-Constructs.html) so you can add the following to make the `SPACE: magic-space` keybinding only apply to Bash:

```
$if Bash
  SPACE: magic-space
$endif
```